# Stuck on 5Ghz WiFi antenna and reach problem

Tags: wifi

I am trying to use outdoor antenna for my indoors modem. I used an stick antenna for first slot with 3 meters cord and 3 meters extension. I used omnidirectional antenna for second slot with same cord setup. Second antenna is [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BLRC738D). With original indoors antennas, I can get up to 75 meters range in outdoor if nothing is in between modem and receiver. But with the antennas the range is around 10 meters outdoors. Should I buy a more expensive antenna with higher gain or extending the antenna cords is my problem? Really looking forward to some insights to this issue.
Thanks.